# Docker image creation for spring boot application which uses library in jfrog

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-image

I am getting error while creating docker image for a spring boot microservice(XMDService) which is using  library in jfrog(I have added the dependencies for these libraries in `pom.xml` file  and repository also .)

I copied settings.xml to the  current directory. And I am getting  401 Unauthorized error.

```
       <java.version>11</java. Version>
       <spring-cloud. Version>2021.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
   </properties>


       <repositories>
       <repository>
           <snapshots>
               <enabled>false</enabled>
           </snapshots>
           <id>central</id>
           <name>maven2</name>
           <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
       </repository>
.       <repository>
           <snapshots>
               <enabled>false</enabled>
           </snapshots>
           <id>xtgcentral</id>
           <name>xtplatformlibraries-libs-release-local</name>
         <url>https://xtintech.jfrog.io/artifactory/xtplatformlibraries-libs-release-local</url>
       </repository>
.
.
<repositories>
   <dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
           <scope>test</scope>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.xtintech.xal</groupId>
           <artifactId>xalservicesapi</artifactId>
           <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>`enter code here`
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.xtintech.xal</groupId>
           <artifactId>xalplatformlibraries</artifactId>
           <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.xtintech.xal</groupId>
           <artifactId>simulatorxmdiserviceapi</artifactId>
           <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
           <scope>runtime</scope>
           <optional>true</optional>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.xtintech.xpl</groupId>
           <artifactId>loggingframework</artifactId>
           <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.xtintech.xpl</groupId>
           <artifactId>platformapi</artifactId>
           <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
       </dependency>



# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jre-jammy

COPY .mvn/ .mvn
COPY mvnw pom.xml ./
COPY mvnw settings.xml ./
RUN ./mvnw -s settings.xml dependency:resolve

COPY src ./src

CMD ["./mvnw", "spring-boot:run"]
```

Comment: Please show your `pom.xml` and the full error (as it is only a partial snippet and the interesting parts are actually missing).

Comment: If those are local libraries they should be in your local maven repo. Why would docker fail? Are you using a multistage build and use maven inside docker? If so you need to copy those local dependencies to the docker container as well and its local maven repo.

Comment: Thank you for your reply..I have updated the question. my library is in jfrog and credentials are given in settings.xml file in current directory. But now I am getting unauthorized error.Actually  I am new to spring boot, docker ....

Comment: `settings.xml` doesn't go in the current directory it goes in the user home directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you use local libraries you should add copy statments to your dockerfile, in which you copy the needed libraries to the right place I guess.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Kerem . Do you know which folder I should copy?

Answer (score 0):

Because your libraries do not exist in any maven repository so when installing maven cannot recornize it..

The simply solution is that copy your libraries into a folder and then add them to maven like below

```
<dependency>
    <artifactId>..</artifactId>
    <groupId>..</groupId>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/dependency.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Step to build dockerfile

1. create a jar/war file by using maven
2. copy the jar/war file to docker in dockerfile
3. up to you

Comment: Thank you for your reply..I have updated the question..now I am getting unauthorized  error

Comment: Your jfrog repository is private so it required basic authentication.. following the link here to setup it https://mymavenrepo.com/docs/maven.auth.html

Comment: I have added authentication in settings.xml file